# How to make autoincrement string in java to insert MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, auto-increment

i was writing some codes. i set my Primary Key is varchar. and i want to make it autoincrement like FT001. my code was working but until it FT10 it cant increment again. i dont know the codes or query is wrong.
here is my code:

```
    private void autoNumber(){
        try{
            String autonumber = "SELECT MAX(right(no_faktur,1)) FROM transaksi";
            Connection con = Koneksi.getConnection();
            Statement statement = (Statement) con.createStatement();
            ResultSet r = statement.executeQuery(autonumber);
            while (r.next()){
                if (r.first() == false){
                    textFaktur.setText("FT001");
                }else{
                    r.last();
                    int faktur = r.getInt(1)+1;
                    String number = String.valueOf(faktur);
                    int fakturlong = number.length();
                    for (int i = 0; i<2-fakturlong;i++){
                        number = "00"+number;
                    }
                    textFaktur.setText("FT"+number);

                }
            }
            statement.close();
            r.close();
        }catch(SQLException e){

        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not use a number as auto-increment? It would be so much easier!

Comment: i know, but what can i do ? i just get it from UML analysis. it should be String+int

Comment: Can't you just add the string after reading it from the DB? Or store it in another column if it is individual?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when value FT10 is inserted, your query (SELECT MAX(right(no_faktur,1)) FROM transaksi) is still returning 9, since you are looking for the MAX value of 1 character, which will always be 9.

Comment: Instead of looking for the character at the right side, you could for instance trim the letters 'FT' from the left.
Then you can apply MAX function to the result

Answer (score 0):

You can use that column as `auto increment`, but you should specify the field as number not text.

Create that table as

```
CREATE TABLE transaksi(
     no_faktur Int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (no_faktur )
);
```

Then you don't need to manually find the last `no_faktur` inserted. the table itself automatically increment that field each time you insert records into the table

Comment: i know auto increment, the analyst want me to do String+int as Primary.

Answer (score 0):

I think i got the answer:

```
Ps=con.preparestatement("select * from tablename");
Resultset rs=ps.execute query();
if(rs.last())
{
    String aidv ="TAR" 1;
}
else
{
    int id=RS.getRow();
    id  ;
    aidv="TAR" id;
}
```

Comment: Please also explain how and why this might help